# How does the compiler benefit from C++'s new final keyword?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, final, c++11

C++11 will allow to mark classes and virtual method to be *final* to prohibit deriving from them or overriding them.

```
class Driver {
  virtual void print() const;
};
class KeyboardDriver : public Driver {
  void print(int) const final;
};
class MouseDriver final : public Driver {
  void print(int) const;
};
class Data final {
  int values_;
};
```

This is very useful, because it tells the reader of the interface something about the intent of the use of this class/method. That the user gets diagnostics if he tries to override might be useful, too.

**But is there an advantage from the compilers point of view?** Can the compiler do anything different when he knows "this class will never be derived from" or "this virtual function will never be overridden"?

For `final` I mainly found only N2751 referring to it. Sifting through some of the discussions I found arguments coming from the C++/CLI side, but no clear hint why `final` may be useful for the compiler. I am thinking about this, because I also see some disadvantages of marking a class `final`: To unit-test protected member functions one can derive a class and insert test-code. Sometimes these classes are good candidates to be marked with `final`. This technique would be impossible in these cases.

Comment: "this virtual function will never be overridden" -- the call would not need to rely on dynamic dispatch (methods/destructors) in this case. it's up to the compiler writers to choose to make this optimization. considering the correctness/strictness of c++, *i* would personally like to see it. the same optimization could be made for instances when the compiler knows the type (e.g. initialized within sight or as a typed member variable). more important than the overhead of the virtual call, there is often the ability to inline or optimize based on the expanded knowledge of the execution.

Comment: I don't really see what it matters. The purpose of `override` and `final` is to allow the compiler to stop the user from screwing up. You should use them to stop yourself and others from doing the wrong thing. That the compiler might or might not make something faster is really irrelevant, because you should _always_ be using them where appropriate anyway.

Answer (score 36):

I can think of one scenario where it might be helpful to the compiler from an optimisation perspective. I'm not sure if it's worth the effort to compiler implementers, but it's theoretically possible at least.

With `virtual` call dispatch on a derived, `final` type you can be sure that there is nothing else deriving from that type. This means that (at least in theory) the `final` keyword would make it possible to correctly resolve some `virtual` calls at compile time, which would make a number of optimisations possible that were otherwise impossible on `virtual` calls.

For example, if you have `delete most_derived_ptr`, where `most_derived_ptr` is a pointer to a derived, `final` type then it's possible for the compiler to simplify calls to the `virtual` destructor.

Likewise for calls to `virtual` member functions on references/pointers to the most derived type.

I'd be very surprised if any compilers did this today, but it seems like the kind of thing that might be implemented over the next decade or so.

There might also be some millage in being able to infer that (in the absence of `friend`s) things marked `protected` in a `final` `class` also effectively become `private`.

Comment: +1, why this was a comment in first place. This is worth an answer

Comment: It started as a comment because I thought it was going to be a throw away "there might be an answer here" hint/remark, until I realised I'd edited the comment enough to basically write an answer instead of a throw away hint!

Comment: Would this in its best case even allow to **inline** those not-virtual-anymore function calls? That could be huge benefit! And it would make the `inline` hint make sense for `virtual` functions, ie. destructors-

Comment: @towi Any call that can be resolved at compile-time can be inlined. (In actuality, you can speculatively inline calls regardless, with dispatch logic if it turns out you don't actually want what you've inlined. No idea whether any C++ compiler does this, but this is the entire premise of inlining in JIT compilers for dynamic languages.)

Comment: @gsnedders: JITs can make sure that the types they're speculatively inlining have occurred at least once at the call site, no such guarantee with C++ so it's much harder to know if it's a win. The compiler would have to be able to prove that it's at least some of the time going to be type X at compile time, which sounds tricky. Still, dunno whether any compilers do it, they could exist.

Answer (score 32):

Virtual calls to functions are slightly more costly that normal calls. In addition to actually performing the call, the runtime must first determine which function to call, which oftens leads to:

1. Locating the v-table pointer, and through it reaching the v-table
2. Locating the function pointer within the v-table, and through it performing the call

Compared to a direct call where the address of the function is known in advance (and hard-coded with a symbol), this leads to a small overhead. Good compilers manage to make it only 10%-15% slower than a regular call, which is usually insignificant if the function has any meat.

A compiler's optimizer still seeks to avoid all kinds of overhead, and **devirtualizing** function calls is generally a low-hanging fruit. For example, see in C++03:

```
struct Base { virtual ~Base(); };

struct Derived: Base { virtual ~Derived(); };

void foo() {
  Derived d; (void)d;
}
```

Clang gets:

```
define void @foo()() {
  ; Allocate and initialize `d`
  %d = alloca i8**, align 8
  %tmpcast = bitcast i8*** %d to %struct.Derived*
  store i8** getelementptr inbounds ([4 x i8*]* @vtable for Derived, i64 0, i64 2), i8*** %d, align 8

  ; Call `d`'s destructor
  call void @Derived::~Derived()(%struct.Derived* %tmpcast)

  ret void
}
```

As you can see, the compiler was already smart enough to determine that `d` being a `Derived` then it is unnecessary to incur the overhead of virtual call.

In fact, it would optimize the following function just as nicely:

```
void bar() {
  Base* b = new Derived();
  delete b;
}
```

However there are some situations where the compiler cannot reach this conclusion:

```
Derived* newDerived();

void deleteDerived(Derived* d) { delete d; }
```

Here we could expect (naively) that a call to `deleteDerived(newDerived());` would result in the same code than before. However it is not the case:

```
define void @foobar()() {
  %1 = tail call %struct.Derived* @newDerived()()
  %2 = icmp eq %struct.Derived* %1, null
  br i1 %2, label %_Z13deleteDerivedP7Derived.exit, label %3

; <label>:3                                       ; preds = %0
  %4 = bitcast %struct.Derived* %1 to void (%struct.Derived*)***
  %5 = load void (%struct.Derived*)*** %4, align 8
  %6 = getelementptr inbounds void (%struct.Derived*)** %5, i64 1
  %7 = load void (%struct.Derived*)** %6, align 8
  tail call void %7(%struct.Derived* %1)
  br label %_Z13deleteDerivedP7Derived.exit

_Z13deleteDerivedP7Derived.exit:                  ; preds = %3, %0
  ret void
}
```

Convention could dictate that `newDerived` returns a `Derived`, but the compiler cannot make such an assumption: and what if it returned something further derived ? And thus you get to see all the ugly machinery involved in retrieving the v-table pointer, selecting the appropriate entry in the table and finally performing the call.

If however we put a `final` in, then we give the compiler a guarantee that it cannot be anything else:

```
define void @deleteDerived2(Derived2*)(%struct.Derived2* %d) {
  %1 = icmp eq %struct.Derived2* %d, null
  br i1 %1, label %4, label %2

; <label>:2                                       ; preds = %0
  %3 = bitcast i8* %1 to %struct.Derived2*
  tail call void @Derived2::~Derived2()(%struct.Derived2* %3)
  br label %4

; <label>:4                                      ; preds = %2, %0
  ret void
}
```

In short: `final` allows the compiler to avoid the overhead of virtual calls for the concerned functions in situations where detecting it is impossible.

Comment: So, there *is* already a compiler which can almost directly benefit from this, by applying his optimization magic? *Clang* is almost final-ready?

Comment: The real benefit would come from not only de-virtualizing, but also to inline. Is it (theoretically) possible to let the compiler even inline those de-virtualized calls?

Comment: @towi: yes it is possible to inline. Devirtualization in Clang comes very early because it's an optimization done in the front-end (the optimizer is not OO aware). Therefore, once the call is devirtualized all optimizations that can be done on regular functions are possible. Whether they actually occur of course depends on whether the optimizer think they are a good idea. As for the first question, I do not think that Clang is completely final ready, though it already benefits from it in some places. I crafted the last devirtualization manually actually ;)

Comment: "_Good compilers manage to make it only 10%-15% slower than a regular call_" which compiles achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

Depending how you look at it, there's a further benefit to the compiler (although that benefit simply redounds to the user, so arguably this isn't a compiler benefit): the compiler can avoid emitting warnings for constructs with uncertain behavior were a thing to be overridable.

For example, consider this code:

```
class Base
{
  public:
    virtual void foo() { }
    Base() { }
    ~Base();
};

void destroy(Base* b)
{
  delete b;
}
```

Many compilers will emit a warning for `b`'s non-virtual destructor when the `delete b` is observed.  If a class `Derived` inherited from `Base` and had its own `~Derived` destructor, using `destroy` on a dynamically-allocated `Derived` instance would usually (per spec behavior is undefined) call `~Base`, but it would not call `~Derived`.  Thus `~Derived`'s cleanup operations wouldn't happen, and that could be bad (although probably not catastrophic, in most cases).

If the compiler knows that `Base` can't be inherited from, however, then it's no problem that `~Base` is non-virtual, because no derived cleanup can be accidentally skipped.  Adding `final` to `class Base` gives the compiler the information to not emit a warning.

I know for a fact that using `final` in this way will suppress a warning with Clang.  I don't know if other compilers emit a warning here, or if they take finality into account in determining whether or not to emit a warning.

Comment: It should have a new warning: warning 3: completely pointless use of the virtual keyword - please remove it.

Comment: In this case, yeah, the extra warning might be nice.  But note that unless the class has internal linkage, some entirely separate class in an entirely separate file might inherit from it (I...think this is okay as long as the two definitions are identical, per the One Definition Rule), in another compilation unit the compiler can't see.  So it's not always possible for a compiler to emit such a warning, when it might seem it could.

Comment: perhaps it could be implemented in the linker instead

Comment: Yeah, I think it could.  In practice I think linkers tend not to be so closely tied to linking C++, that they have the knowledge or intelligence to expose such a warning.  :-(