# Does final keyword in c++ allow for additional compiler optimizations?

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual, compiler-optimization, final

I was thinking about virtual calls and how they work. I understand that virtual calls can be inlined and hardcoded at compile time for value types. If the pointer type is of a class declared as final (like sealed in c#) could this allow the compiler to do the same thing?

Is this done a lot in current compilers or is it just theoretical/too small to worry about?

Comment: I'm also curious. The term you're looking for is "devirtualization" btw. My guess is a type marked "final" would at the very least make the analysis easier for the compiler.

Comment: I believe you're right, yet it's better to check the generated code to prove it. It doesn't seem to be too hard to do.

Comment: Yes, you should see devirtualization if the type (or virtual function) is marked `final`.

Comment: C++ compiler optimizers already "devirtualized" functions if they could tell which function ends up getting invoked.  Before C++11.  Requirement is that the allocation ends up near the invocation, either explicitly in the code or by getting code inlined. The *final* keyword does not change that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the compiler benefit from C++'s new final keyword?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7538820/how-does-the-compiler-benefit-from-cs-new-final-keyword)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the calls can be devirtualized if the virtual function or the class is declared `final`. For example, given

```
struct B {
  virtual void f() = 0;
};

struct D1 : B {
  virtual void f();
};

struct D2 : B {
  virtual void f() final;
};

struct D3 final : D1 {};

void f1(D1 * d) { d->f(); }
void f2(D2 * d) { d->f(); }
void f3(D3 * d) { d->f(); }
```

Clang at `-O1` or higher [generates](http://goo.gl/F88HOU) this assembly:

```
f1(D1*):                              # @f1(D1*)
    movq    (%rdi), %rax
    jmpq    *(%rax)  # TAILCALL

f2(D2*):                              # @f2(D2*)
    jmp D2::f()              # TAILCALL

f3(D3*):                              # @f3(D3*)
    jmp D1::f()              # TAILCALL
```

Note that `f1` calls through the vtable, while the calls in `f2` and `f3` are devirtualized.

Answer (score 2):

> I was thinking about virtual calls and how they work. I understand that virtual calls can be inlined and hardcoded at compile time for value types. If the pointer type is of a class declared as final (like sealed in c#) could this allow the compiler to do the same thing?

Yes, in `gcc` calls to final members and through final classes will be devirtualised, and [here's the code](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/gcc/cp/call.c#L7186-L7190) that does it.