# Are methods of the final class applied to pointer to function optimization by default?

Tags: c++, c++11, vtable

As mentioned here:
[How does the compiler benefit from C++'s new final keyword?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7538820/how-does-the-compiler-benefit-from-cs-new-final-keyword)
and as stated in this question, `final` keyword for methods can optimize vtable calls to calls by simple function pointers.

If I have class:

```
class Derived final : public Base
{
virtual void Foo() override;
//virtual void Foo() final override; Are these statements equal?
}
```

Will compiler mark such methods as final and apply function pointers instead of vtable?
I'm interested in vc120 and clang compilers behavior with highest optimization level set.

Comment: As class is `final`, you can no longer inherit from it, and so cannot override the virtual method in a derived class.

Comment: @Jarod42, Yep, I upgraded question title, I'm interested in question about optimization applied

Comment: It is up to the compiler to apply any optimization as long as it respect as-if rule. I would expect from a compiler equal optimization from the both form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing stopping a compiler from deducing `Foo` can't be overriden further. Since you specified Clang in your question, here's a sample code I tested on Clang 5 with -O1:

```
struct Base {
    virtual void Foo() = 0;
};

struct  Derived final : public Base
{
virtual void Foo() override {}
//virtual void Foo() final override; Are these statements equal?
};

Derived* getD();

int main() {

    getD()->Foo();

    return 0;
}
```

It produced this (<kbd>[Live on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/wWiE4h)</kbd>):

```
main:                                   # @main
        push    rax
        call    _Z4getDv
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    _ZN7Derived3FooEv
        xor     eax, eax
        pop     rcx
        ret
_ZN7Derived3FooEv:                      # @_ZN7Derived3FooEv
        ret
```

As you can see, the compiler is perfectly able to deduce it may call `Derived::Foo` directly.

Comment: As I know, even if `final` is not in code, optimizer also can substitute vtable to function call. `final` is a design keyword (like `override`) and basic goal is not optimization, but it is only ability to optimize some places using information provided by `final`. Right?

Comment: @BohdanBessonov - Proving that a general virtual function is not overriden requires program wide analysis (and think about interfaces that come from DLLs). It's intractable in general. But since the compiler knows that the `final` specifier **guarantees** no overrides are possible, the problem is easily solvable. So it's a very valuable specifier to have.